# Only collect nested objects of a json API response

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I have a project that uses Retrofit and Moshi. The API I'm using provides a response along these lines:

```
{
    "response": {
        "nameObjects": [{
                "name": "Name 1",
                "number": 123
            },
            {
                "name": "Name 2",
                "number": 456
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As a result my model looks as follows:

```
data class ApiResponse(response: Response)
data class Response(nameObjects: List<NameObject>)
data class NameObject(name: String: number: Int)
```

With the following api call:

```
@GET("/people/search")
suspend getPeopleWithNumbers(): ApiResponse
```

Given that the only part I really need here is `NameObject` this really introduces a lot of junk to my code. What I'm really looking for is something that's allow me to just have this:

```
data class NameObject(name: String: number: Int)
```

and

```
@GET("/names/search")
suspend getNameObjects(): List<NameObject>
```

I know I could use a custom adapter with moshi to only extract only the parts I'm looking for, but that would require me to manually parse json, which would be inconvenient, potentially slow and error prone. Is there a may to make this happen with either moshi or another json parsing library out of the box?

Comment: Can you improvent your question, I don't know what is your point

Comment: The best way to do it right is to ask a backend guy to rethink this stupid response structure and make it conviniane.

Comment: Instead of Moshi, try using Gson.

Comment: I've always had good experiences using Jackson. A lot of the details of deserializing can be defined declaratively with annotations. A full list here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations. You can avoid the `ApiResponse` object by using `@JsonRootName` on `Response`, but I think you would still need two classes. Sounds like you just want `NameObject` and to get a list of those without having `response`

Comment: @mowwwalker that's exactly what I'd like to have

Comment: @SpaciTron definitely look into Jackson then :)